# How to use java stream to convert a List of some class to a list/set of any one property of class?

Tags: java, list, class, set, java-stream

I have a class

```
class Student{  
int id; 
 String name;   
 public static void main(String args[]){   
  Student s1=new Student();
  System.out.println(s1.id); 
  System.out.println(s1.name);  
 }  
}
```

I have a list of class student say, `List<Student> students` whose size is 100.

I want to stream id of all the students and save it in a set `Set<int>id`, one easy way to do it is using a for loop, can someone please tell how the same can be implemented using java stream API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```java
List<Student> students = /* ... */;
Set<Integer> studentIds = students.stream()
        .map(s -> s.id)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

And if your Students object has a getter method for the ID, you can directly [reference the method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html):

```java
public class Student {
  private int id;
  public int getId() {
    return this.id;
  }
}

Set<Integer> studentIds = students.stream()
        .map(Student::getId) // <-
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

**Note:** Note: primitive data types (`int`) cannot be used as [generic parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/boundedTypeParams.html), so you must use [wrapper classes](https://www.javatpoint.com/wrapper-class-in-java).
=> `Set<Integer>` instead of `Set<int>`